# Ionic2, how to import custom plugin (appsee or uxcam) into Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, uxcam

I am trying to use [Appsee](https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/ionic) or [UXcam](https://uxcam.com/docs)

I tried import like below, but no luck
// import { Appsee } from '@ionic-native/appsee';

Else where i saw that you have to declare the variable in question for typescript to recognize the variable, I did that like below

**declare var cordova:any;**

```
// import { Appsee } from '@ionic-native/appsee';

declare var cordova:any;

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage:any = LoginPage;       // FOR TESTING

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
    cordova.plugins.Appsee.start("my key");

      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

I've also tried adding public appsee: Appsee to the constructor but still no luck.

Any guidance is appreciated. I'm getting ***ReferenceError: cordova is not defined.***

How do I import a custom plugin, [appsee](https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/ionic)

edit adding suggested code 
declare var Appsee:any;

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;       // FOR TESTING

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
    Appsee.start("my key");

      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put it under the `imports` as shown below.

```
//your other imports here

declare var Appsee:any;

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
```

Comment: thanks for replying. Place that statement in my app.module.ts or app.components.ts? I tried doing it under the imports in the module.ts file and that gives me error

When I place that statement above the constructor of component.ts file i'm getting a reference error...

Comment: You need to put the place where you use it. It seems you're using inside the `app.components.ts`. So put there. Put it just under the `import`.

Comment: see my edited code, if that's correct, i'm still getting a reference error

Comment: yea, i tried that initally but still getting a refernce error (appsee isn't defined)

Comment: Did you run this `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appsee --save`

Comment: yes, i did. The plugin is saved in my config.xml file. as <plugin name="cordova-plugin-appsee" spec="~2.3.65" />

Comment: You need to test this on `device` or `emulator`.

Comment: might that be the case? I shall see what i can do. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: My pleasure... :)