# Ionic app not working, Cannot find module 'cordova-plugin-appsee'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I  am taking over a Cordova/Ionic project. I've never worked with Cordova or Ionic before, so I am complete beginner in that area. However, I have worked with Node, on and off, for a few years, so I mostly know about that.

I asked a question and implemented the solution:

[How to register code with the deviceready event in a Cordova / Ionic project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325892/how-to-register-code-with-the-deviceready-event-in-a-cordova-ionic-project)

That left me with this problem:

[Ionic2, how to import custom plugin (appsee or uxcam) into Ionic App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645037/ionic2-how-to-import-custom-plugin-appsee-or-uxcam-into-ionic-app)

I'm not clear what the answer on that page means.

Right now, in this file:

```
src/app/app.component.ts
```

I now have this import statements:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav, App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { TabsPage } from "../pages/tabs/tabs";
import { ProfilePersonThingsPage } from "../pages/profile-person-things/profile-person-things";
import { CreateProfileBasicsPage } from '../pages/create-profile-basics/create-profile-basics';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';
import { ProfileOwnerEditPage } from '../pages/profile-owner-edit/profile-owner-edit';
import { AlertScreen } from '../providers/services/alertScreen.service';
import { ApiProvider } from '../providers/api/api';
import { SUCCESS_STATUS, ERROR_STATUS, ACCESS_DENIED, TypeTabIndex , TypePush} from '../constants/config';
import { LoadingScreenProvider } from '../providers/services/loadingScreen.service';
import { ProfileOwnerSettingsPage } from '../pages/profile-owner-settings/profile-owner-settings';
import { ProfileOwnerSupportPage } from '../pages/profile-owner-support/profile-owner-support';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProfilePersonPage } from '../pages/profile-person/profile-person';
import { SocketProvider } from '../providers/services/socket.service';
import { ShareProvider } from '../providers/services/share.service';
import { PushNotificationComponent } from "../components/push-notification/push-notification";
import { ConversationPage } from './../pages/conversation/conversation';
import { PushNotificationProvider } from './../providers/services/pushnotification.service';

import { Appsee } from 'cordova-plugin-appsee';
```

But if I run:

```
ionic serve
```

this last line throws an error:

```
typescript: src/app/app.component.ts, line: 26 
    Cannot find module 'cordova-plugin-appsee'.
```

If I look here:

https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/ionic

The documentation suggests this is all I have to do:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appsee
```

which I have done.

If I do this:

```
find . -name "*appsee*"
```

I see this:

```
./plugins/cordova-plugin-appsee
./plugins/cordova-plugin-appsee/src/android/appsee.jar
```

If I delete this line:

```
import { Appsee } from 'cordova-plugin-appsee';
```

And then I run `ionic serve` then the app starts up without error, but as soon as I try to load a page, I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Appsee is not defined ReferenceError: Appsee is not defined at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:6422:13 at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9283) at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4509:37) at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9223) at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4452) at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14076 at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9967) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4500:37) at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:9888) at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:5143)
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Also, in the earlier question, that I link to, someone put this in a comment:

```
You need to test this on device or emulator. – Sampath Dec 5 '17 at 2:47
```

What does that mean?

Comment: did you ever get a fix for this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://www.appsee.com/docs/android/ionic)

In case you're using TypeScript (default in ionic 2 and ionic 3) place the following line under the imports:

```
declare var Appsee:any;
```

Comment: Yes, that is there, right after the import statements.